# Cheetah #include doesn't place #def within scope

Tags: python, cheetah

When I include a file using #include (without raw) it parses the content correctly, but the #def which I want to access within the original file doesn't exist & an error is thrown.

Base Template:

```
#def sayHello($name)
hello $name
#end def
```

Template:

```
#include "../../BaseTemplate.template"
$sayHello("fred")
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason this is happening is that `sayHello` is a function added to "Base Template" (which is actually a class), but you can't access that in the calling template.

I'm not sure the best way to solve the problem you're having, but I believe you can make `defHello` a static method with `#@staticmethod` before the `def` line, and then import the template instead of including it.

[This page](http://packages.python.org/Cheetah/recipes/staticmethod.html) has more information.

Answer (score 0):

Well, looks like you can do this through the attribute:

```
self._CHEETAH__cheetahIncludes
```

Which is a dictionary that contains all of your includes.

Use it from your template after the include like:

```
 $self._CHEETAH__cheetahIncludes[include_id].the_function(*args)
```

For me the `include_id` happened to be the file path (I found this out by printing out the `_CHEETAH__cheetahIncludes` dictionary first, heh).  Is this guaranteed? No idea.

Do I recommend this? No.  Is there a better way to access the function?  Appears to not be.  Are there any shortcomings?  No idea, use at your own risk.  Could this be useful to someone?  Maybe :)

I mean it could be a useful feature because people are trying to do it, but is this feature necessary?  Probably not.

My use case was I wanted to reuse a snippet that would access the parents searchList as includes do, but I wanted to reuse this include with a single hard coded argument in other templates.  **I could easily just make this variable that changes the behavior part of the searchList in the first place, and that is probably what you should do as well :).  This would also allow me to pass it in from the application layer instead of hard coding it in my template!**

This is most likely good design because it prevents the shorts cuts us developers will often take if allowed to do so easily.